# Using XML in a SQL query

Tags: xml, r, ms-access

I am trying to query an ACCESS database using R v3.0.3 and am running into repeated SQL syntax errors.  My code is as follows.

```
library(RODBC) 
library(XML)

# Access directory containing the corpus scripts and load all corpus documents    
dale1   <- "C:/Cerberus_Software_Prototype/TR_Corpus/2286newsML.xml")    
doc1    <- xmlInternalTreeParse(dale1)    
xattrs  <- xpathApply(doc1, "//code[@code]", xmlGetAttr, "code")     
xmldf   <- xmlToDataFrame(nodes = getNodeSet(doc1, "//code/code"))      
xattrs1 <- data.frame(xattrs)

# Connect to Accessdb
channel <- odbcConnectAccess("C:/Cerberus_Software_Prototype/R/Economics_data/Cerberus1.mdb")

for (i in 1:6) {
   #  MODIFY SELECT OR ACTION QUERY TO MEET NEEDS, EVEN ADD PARAMS  
   querydf <- sqlQuery(channel, paste0("select All_codes.Description from All_codes 
                                        where All_codes.Code ='", xattrs$[i]Code, "'"))        
 }

close(channel)
```

The XML is contained within an XML structure (only pasting the relevant part here) In this example there are six values within the "code code=" block

```
<code code="ECAT">
    <editdetail attribution="BIP Coding Group" action="confirmed" date="1996-08-20"/>
</code>
```

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: You need to tell people what the syntax errors are not just that you get a lot of them.

Comment: I've just closed R down (32-bit version) and attempted to run the script again. It generates the following error. Error in query querydf[i] <- sqlQuery(channel, paste0("select All_codes.Description from All_codes where All_codes.Code ='", xattrs[i], "'")) Object query not found. This code only seems to work for a particular session, once my pc is switched off it generates this error and I can't understand why that is the case. –  Dale Addison 15 mins ago

Answer (score 0):

In your SQL statement change the concatenated variable:

```
xattrs$[i]Code
```

To

```
xattrs[i]
```

Comment: So far it seems to work, does anyone know if there is a way to count the number of xml data elements in each node to use in the for loop?

Comment: Sure, use `length(xattrs)`. Please accept if solution worked.